# How to adding day to Date with DateToolsSwift?

Tags: swift, date, cocoapods

I'm using a package call DateToolsSwift. Now, whenever I want to add a day to a Date object, I would do like this

```
let date = Date().add(TimeChunk(seconds: 0, minutes: 0, hours: 0, days: 3, weeks: 0, months: 0, years: 0))
```

This code is too long and it does't feel right. So my question is, is this the way to do it in DateToolsSwift? Or I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in API? `let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding:.day, value: 3, to: Date())`

Comment: @vadian Nothing wrong with it but it just more easier to use DateTools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DateToolsSwift package defines extension methods in [Integer+DateTools.swift](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools/blob/master/DateToolsSwift/DateTools/Integer%2BDateTools.swift) which allow the simple creation of
`TimeChunk`s, e.g. `3.days` or `2.weeks`. Therefore you can do

```
let date = Date().add(3.days)
```

or, since DateToolsSwift also defines a custom `+` operator,

```
let date = Date() + 3.days
```

Answer (score 6):

*Without using DateToolsSwift. For example, if you want to add 3 days to Jan 1, 1970

```
let aDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
var dateComponent = DateComponents()
dateComponent.day = 3
let next3Days = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: aDate)
```

Similarly, you can set `aDate = Date()` if you want to add days to today.

EDIT

Alternatively, from @CodeDifferent

```
let next3Days = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 3, to: aDate)!
```

Comment: If you are adding only 1 time unit, like in this case, there's a more convenient function: `let next3Days = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 3, to: aDate)!`